# How to find an "upper margin" for data on visits

Tags: descriptive-statistics, extreme-value

For a handful of store locations, I have data on each entrance and exit time.
I have counted the total num of people at a store at any given minute.
I am trying to find out the values for which the store is full/crowded, given that I do not have the area of the store nor an official limit of the max headcount.
An assumption must be made, for the given data time interval a situation of a full/crowded store did happen several times.

How should I go about it? only to take the max(total headcount in a given time) if to restrict

Comment: Can you show some plots of the data?

Comment: @user2974951 sorry, it is commercial data, I can not

Answer (score 0):

You could use [extreme value theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theory) (EVT) models. Those models are used for modeling extremes. For example, if you have data on the largest floods that happened in a particular area, you could use EVT to predict the size of the [1000-year flood](https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/what-1000-year-flood). The same, given the data on the peak number of customers you could fit a model to it to predict the highest peak possible (with a given probability). In practice, this could mean fitting [Gumbel distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution) (or other model) and finding the [quantile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile) at a given cutoff. You could ask "Given this distribution of the maximums of the number of people, what is the maximum that has a chance of happening less than 1%", and the answer would be given by the quantile function $Q_X$ of your data $X$,

$$
x_{1\%} = Q_X(1 - 0.1) 
$$

so by the definition of the quantile function

$$
\Pr[X \le x_{1\%}] = 0.1
$$

Notice however that this ignores the fact that the stores have some fixed capacity, beyond which no more people would fit. Knowing this capacity, which should be available in the store architectural documentation, would be really useful for you as it would almost give the answer (probably more people could fit in practice as compared to the safe or legal limit). If you knew the area of the stores, you could easily make a back-of-the-napkin estimate by dividing the total area of the area of an average human and subtracting some area occupied by shelves and other objects. The areas would also help a lot if you would be building a more complicated model that could be applied to different stores as you would need to take into considerations that they differ in areas.